# How to access nested json object and display markers using that in leaflet map with conditional marker rendering

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

This is my json data from an API:

```
{"datapoint":[{"id":"H0031","In_time":{"date":"2017-10-24 10:41:17.783000"},"lat1":"24.55","long1":"71.75","lat2":"27.715186","long2":"83.323999"}]}
```

I want to iterate over **date** and display multiple markers.

Here is my full code:

```
fetch('http://www.example.com/?qty=10')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            let datapoint = response.datapoint;
            for (let i=0; i<datapoint.length; i++) {

                let hlat = parseFloat(datapoint[i]["lat1"]);
                let hlon = parseFloat(datapoint[i]["long1"]);
                let glat = parseFloat(datapoint[i]["lat2"]);
                let glon = parseFloat(datapoint[i]["long2"]);
                let markerLocation1 = new L.LatLng(hlat, hlon);
                let marker1 = new L.marker(markerLocation1,{icon: greenIcon});
                marker1.addTo(map).bindPopup(popup,customOptions);
                let markerLocation2 = new L.LatLng(glat, glon);
                let marker2 = new L.marker(markerLocation2,{icon: BlueIcon});
                marker2.addTo(map).bindPopup(popup,customOptions);
                var latlngs=[];
                let latlng1=[hlat,hlon];
                let latlng2=[glat,glon];
                var offsetX=latlng2[1]-latlng1[1];
                var offsetY=latlng2[0]-latlng1[0];
                var r=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(offsetX,2)+Math.pow(offsetY,2)), theta = Math.atan2(offsetY,offsetX);
                var thetaoffset=(3.14/10);
                var r2 = (r/2)/(Math.cos(thetaoffset)),
                    theta2 = theta + thetaoffset;
                var midpointX = (r2 * Math.cos(theta2)) + latlng1[1],
                    midpointY = (r2 * Math.sin(theta2)) + latlng1[0];

                var midpointLatLng = [midpointY, midpointX];

                latlngs.push(latlng1, midpointLatLng, latlng2);
                var pathOne = L.curve(['M',latlng2,'Q',midpointLatLng,latlng1], {snakeArray: 5, color:'grey' ,animate: {duration: 2500, iterations: 2}}).addTo(map);

            }

        })
```

..............................................................................................................................................

Comment: Hi. Do you mean you want to iterate over datapoint, extract markers lat1, long1, lat2, long2 and visualize them? date has only dates, how would you build a marker with date info?

Comment: I want to display markers on the basis of the date and time given in **DATE**

Comment: i have to use lat1 lat2 long1 long2 to put the markers but i want to iterate over date

Comment: So you mean you want to render the markers conditionally based on a given date and time?

Comment: yeah, right. :)

Comment: What is the condition? You take the date from the server and you compare it with what with the current date? In your example the given date is passed. I don't get it.

Comment: for example,total data is 50. So i want to display the first 5 i.e ranging from the 2017-10-24 to 5 days before it and so on. After first 5 gets displayed the next 5 i.e from 2017-10-19 to 5 days before should come up and previous one's should disappear

Comment: You should include all this description in your question and probably change the title to conditional marker rendering or sth. The current question title disorientates and someone might thinks that you simply want to access the json and display the markers on the map

Comment: I'm sorry, i have updated it. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Umm, else could you please tell me how to access nested json data from an api?

Comment: I could help you with accessing the json
but regarding the conditional rendering it is not quite clear for me what you want to achieve. Is it ok for you if I give an answer regarding accessing the json and visualize the markers only? Will that help you?

Comment: Yeah, that would help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer to demonstrate to you an example using an API similar example.

I created an extra file with name data.geojson to store the geojson there to imitate the api url:

```
{
  "datapoint": [{
      "id": "H0031",
      "In_time": {
        "date": "2017-10-24 10:41:17.783000"
      },
      "lat1": "24.55",
      "long1": "71.75",
      "lat2": "27.715186",
      "long2": "83.323999"
    },
    {
      "id": "H0032",
      "In_time": {
        "date": "2017-10-25 10:41:17.783000"
      },
      "lat1": "28.55",
      "long1": "74.75",
      "lat2": "29.715186",
      "long2": "88.323999"
    }
  ]
}
```

The js code:

```
let geojson;
// instead of data.geojson you will place your API url
$.getJSON("data.geojson", function(data) {
  geojson = data;
  const dataPoint = geojson.datapoint;

  // store all the coordinates in this array o be able to iterate over the markers array
  let coordinates = [];

  // populate coordinates array with all the markers
  for (let i = 0; i < dataPoint.length; i++) {
    coordinates.push([Number(dataPoint[i].lat1), Number(dataPoint[i].long1)], [Number(dataPoint[i].lat2), Number(dataPoint[i].long2)]);
  };
  // console.log(coordinates);

  // visualize the markers on the map
  for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    L.marker(coordinates[i]).addTo(map)
      .bindPopup("<b>Latitude:</b> " + coordinates[i][0] + " <b>Longitude:</b> " + coordinates[i][1]);
  };
});
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CtvtGmUzOT3nyR82G3Gr?p=preview)

Comment: Here local data has been used but how do i perform the same thing using the data  from api?

Comment: Suppose lat long were nested in there, then how would i access it

Comment: I know how to access if i use the local data but  don't know how it can be done with an API in use

Comment: @renny Did you check the answer?